# Are there any online data analysis websites for arduino IoT projects?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I am planning on making a system where multiple arduinos monitor the conditions of certain type of plant. (Each arduino monitors its own plant, but the plants are of the same species). Each plant would have a different placement in the yard(varies the light). The plants are watered as normal, without an exact amount of water. The arduinos would measure light, temperature, and soil water content. Each would send it to the cloud. My question is: Is their a cloud service that can analyze and "find" the best conditions(amount of water,light,temperature,etc) for type a plant, based on how healthy the plants are?(The health of the plants would be entered in manually by the person using the system). (Sorry if my question doesn't make sense, please ask me any questions you have ,Thanks.)

Comment: For starters, you would need to have some mechanism to send the data to the cloud since the Arduino cannot do that as standalone, WiFi or Ethernet shield. Arduino also doesn't have enough capability to interact with SQL or comparable database technology, so you would need to send the data to a PC to do the actual cloud processes.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that the arduino requires extra hardware to connect to WiFi. Why do I have to send it to a PC? Why not just send it to a cloud service which analyzes the data?(All the arduino is doing is sending data to a server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send data to cloud you will need an internet shield and given that the individual plants are far apart, you will need a wifi shield for each plant that you want to monitor most likely the yun shield. 
Now for online services, there are a few like Temboo, Pushingbox, Initial State, Cayenne, Xively.
Each of them works differently and you will need to choose which best suit you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My question is kind of old so I don't remember the exact context of why I asked my question. But what I think I was trying to ask was, are there any analytics services that find trends based on data, detects patterns, etc. Since then I have seen services such as Microsoft Azure that can analyze and find trends in data. I have used Temboo before and I don't think it has analytical services or anything like that.

Comment: Temboo don't have analytics services but you can use Temboo to upload the data to Google spreadsheet and then process the data into graphs or whatever

Comment: None of these services will inherently give you an analysis, Dashboards like cayenne can help. But you would still need your business logic layer to compute which plant was in best conditions. You could also try import data into SQL tables and then into SQL CUBE to analyse the data..